# Can I use this Seimans ECCS1 lug on my ITE EQ Load Center neutral bar

Tags: electrical

[image]I have an ITE EQ Load Center catalog number EQ 20 mbb. Home was built around 1970.    I need a neutral lug that accepts a 2 ga wire for a 100 amp breaker to new sub panel. The ITE label says "USE COLLAR STRAP PART B-2096".  But of course ITE is out of business, was purchased by Gould, then Seimens purchased Gould/ITE.

Can I use this Seimans ECCS1 lug? It fits the neutral and ground bar on my main panel, attached by compression under two screws.  Can this lug handle a 100 amp neutral? [image: ECC]

Comment: #2 aluminum is not legal for 100A *subpanel feeder*. Very common error that happens for a reason - they're either in the wrong table, or reading the correct table incorrectly (310.15(B)(16) is correct, however you need to use the 75C column not 90C.)  For 100A subpanel feeder you need #1.  However many people find 90A will suit their needs, and the breaker is cheaper :)

Comment: Would it make a difference if using 2 ga copper for the 100A breaker?

Comment: sure #2 copper is good to 115A.  However it'll break your bank and won't buy you a thing safetywise.  The lugs are aluminum.  The far better safety investment is a torque driver.

Comment: Maybe it's just where I live, but I've never seen a lug like that on the shelf at my local DIY home store, so I'm going to assume you were at an electrical supply house when you took the pic of the lug. Bring a pic of the panel's labeling to them and ask them. A) They'll know, and B) if it won't work, they'll be able to tell (and sell) you exactly the one that will.

Comment: Also, just making sure that this is your _main_ panel, the first one after the meter. I'm seeing both neutral and ground going to the same buss bar, and that's only legal at the main panel.

Comment: The sub panel is right next to the main panel in the pic.  So, I plan to use 2 ga copper.

Comment: The lug came from supplyhouse.com.  And the pic is of the main panel where you see grounds and neutrals sharing the same bus.  Thanks all for your help.

Comment: Well you only need #3 copper for 100A if you go copper. And I agree for a 3 foot run, who cares metalwise.  If you want to use the full 115A you breaker 125A (but don't allow a calculated load over 115).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "Likely".

The ultimate decider would be Siemens via your local Siemens dealer or a direct inquiry.  This is likely to be the successor to the one stated on the panel labeling... Siemens has merged their several lines as much as possible.